# how to send data to PC over JTAG/debugger

Tags: c++, arm, embedded, rtos, jtag

I am using a PEmicro USB Multilink Universal JTAG.

I have a Cortex M4 processor running a custom C++ RTOS with no filesystem.

I need to trace execution of some functions to debug a problem but since I don't have a filesystem, I'd have to use a RAM circular buffer.

**QUESTION**

Is it possible to write the trace data over the JTAG/debugger connection to the PC? Even if this can't be done full-speed, it would still be useful to me.

Comment: Output over the SWO line is possible with some tools, or you can do mailboxing discovered by triggering a breakpoint when the embedded system adds a message.   But most of the time you build an embedded system like this with debug output from a serial UART, and capture that, typically with a logic-level USB UART cable on your dev machine.

Comment: Yes it is possible, but cumbersome. Regarding how to do it, that's far too broad a question for this site.